# Stop/Remove daemon (service) when uninstalling App developed with ElectronJS in Mac OS

Tags: macos, service, electron, daemon, electron-builder

I worked on electronjs to make Mac App.
The problem is when install and run Mac App it sets daemon inside it.
But after uninstalling App, daemon still works which it shouldn't be.
Daemon should be removed before deleting app.
Please help me with solution.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Stack Overflow is not a discussion forum, it is a Question & Answer site where you can ask a **specific** programming question that **can be answered** rather than discussed. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236) and then edit your question to conform with the site guidelines.

Comment: is there any solution for uninstalling mac and removing service at the same time in electron mac app?